# Google Dev-Tools don't show Error

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

please have a look at this screenshot:

[image: My Dev-Tools not Working]

Something is not working correctly on my site and I therefore want to debug it. Dev-tools shows that I have 5 Errors and 1 Warning, but when I CLICK on them, nothing happens. It doesn't bring me to a view, where the errors are shown.

I then search in the network panel, where the errors are shown (although I have to scroll through all requests).

The question is, shouldn't I get redirected to where the errors are shown in a list? (At least this is how it worked in the past for me.)

Comment: Did you activate a filter in the console? (check the icons in the upper-left corner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might happens that console view with the errors was resized and the only caption of the console pane are visible. Another option is the filters mentioned in the comments.
If the errors and warnings were filtered out then you will see the console but it will have only marker that some messages were filtered out.